# Cokernel of the Jacobian Matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, jacobians

For an algebraic variety $V = \mathcal{V}(f_1,\dots,f_m)\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, in smooth points $p$ there is a nice geometric interpretation of the Jacobian $(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)_{ij}\lvert_p$'s kernel, namely the variety's tangent space. But is there such an interpretation for the Jacobian's cokernel, too?

Comment: The cokernel is not an intrinsic invariant of $V$, but depends on the chosen functions $f_1,\ldots,f_m$. For instance, think about the case $V = \mathbf A^1$, given either by no equations in $\mathbf A^1$ (so the cokernel is trivial), or by the equation $x=y$ in $\mathbf A^2$ (so the cokernel is 1-dimensional). The most natural geometric interpretation is not in terms of $V$ but in terms of the map $(f_1,\ldots,f_m) : \mathbf A^n \to \mathbf A^m$.

Comment: I hope this question does get an answer, even if the most naive version doesn't make sense.

Comment: The quotient of the normal cone by the natural action of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}^n$ does have an "intrinsic" nature: it is the "intrinsic normal cone" used by Behrend-Fantechi in their construction of the virtual fundamental class.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn say we fix the polynomial map $(f_1,\dots , f_m):\mathbb{A}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^m$. The cokernel then becomes elements $v\in\mathbb{A}^m$ with $\sum_j v_j\frac{\partial f_j}{x_i}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. In particular, this sum only varies twith $f$′s differentials in a particular coordinate (rather than the coordinate derivatives in the tangent space case). Can we say anything about vectors of this form relative to $(f_1,\dots , f_m)$ or better yet, the variety $V$ that is generated by these polynomials?